# Beamer messes up colors and positioning

Tags: beamer

(This may have been asked before, but I couldn't find it.)

Why does beamer put `no way' at the top left of the slide in blue, but at the center in black when I remove the curly brackets?  Bug or feature?

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{hi}
{
no way
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See section **8.1 The Frame Environment** (p 58) of the [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a feature:

Your second pair of curly brackets concern the subtitle of the frame! If you omit it the frame will be messed up:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{hi}{no way is the subtitle}
% Some stuff to show
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Man, do I feel dumb!

Comment: And thanks; been using Beamer for years and never realized this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you use the curly braces this denotes to beamer that it is a subtitle for the frame.